# Change background-image on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

So i'm using slickslider for creating a slider in my homepage.
The slider large images are 1920 x 700. The slider's height on larger screens is 700px and it's shrinking until 400px on mobile devices.
I want to create a jquery functions that get 2 data attribute from my slides ( data-img-mobile and data-img-large - witch are the links from the images) and than changes the background-image acording to the viewport.( small - large device )
I'm newbie with jquery so can you please help me ? 
Thanks alot !

```
<div class="hero-slider-wraper">
 <div class="hero-slider">
  <div class="hero-slider-component">
   <div class="hero-slider-image" data-img-mobile="" data-img-large="http://sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/home1.jpg" style="background-image:url('http://sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/home1.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="hero-slider-image" style="background-image:url('http://sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/home2.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="hero-slider-image" style="background-image:url('http://sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/home3.jpg');"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Slick Slider is anochered on hero-slider-component

Comment: Some code please. Are you using img tag or image is in background.

Comment: img is in background. i did not tryied to make the script. i will edit with some code

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media queries to achieve this. For example:

```
@media (min-width: 400px) and (@max-width: 600px) // Or whatever the size of your mobile device is.
{
    .hero-slider-image {
        background-image:url('http://www.example.com/mobile-image.jpg')
    }
}

@media (min-width: 601px)
{
    .hero-slider-image {
        background-image:url('http://www.example.com/desktop-image.jpg')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use [`@media`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) method in css.

```
/* This is for desktop and laptop */ 
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .hero-slider-image {
        background-image:url('http://www.example.com/desktop-image.jpg');
    }
}

/* This is for normal tabs */ 
@media screen and (min-width: 751px) {
    .hero-slider-image {
        background-image:url('http://www.example.com/tab-image.jpg');
    }
}

/* This is for mobiles */ 
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .hero-slider-image {
        background-image:url('http://www.example.com/mobile-image.jpg');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but i have 3 slides with different images.

Comment: Give each div an ID and target them that way.